# How to remove or hide Toolbar item in specific page error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, toolbaritems

I am trying to `Remove()` or `Clear()` `ToolbarItems`. Here is my code where I am creating `ToolbarItem` in MainPage.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
   public ToolbarItem cCounter = new ToolbarItem() { Icon = "picture.png" };
   public ToolbarItem pPo = new ToolbarItem() { Text = "-" };

   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
        {
            provider.Clicked += iOS_Ppo_Clicked;
            ToolbarItems.Add(cCounter);
            ToolbarItems.Add(pPo);
        }
    }

    private void iOS_Ppo_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        OpenWindow();            
    }

    public async void OpenWindow()
    {
        if (await Common.WindowComands.CanOpenWindow<PPoPage>(Detail))
        {  
            page = new PPoPage(Page3.Allproviders);

            this.ToolbarItems.Clear(); // here I am getting error:Index was outside the bounds of the array 

            page.OnSelected += Page_OnSelected;
            await Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(page, false);             
        }   
    }
}
```

> Edit: when I included `this.ToolbarItems.Clear();` in `OpenWindow`
>   method which initialise that another page opens and it works! Cleans
>   all toolbar items but unfortunately shows this error:
>
> ```
> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> ```

This items should disappear only for iOS as you see.
Here is my page class where I would like to `Remove()` these `ToolbarItems`:

```
public partial class PPoPage : ContentPage
{
   public MainPage main { get; set; }

   private List<PPo> Pro;

   public PPoPage(List<PPo> po)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
      {
         Pro = po;
         CreateLayout();
         // HERE I WANT TO REMOVE TOOLBARITEMS FOR THIS PAGE
         this.ToolbarItem.Remove(main.cCounter); // here there is error
         this.ToolbarItems.Clear(); // this also doesn't work, because toolbar items still exist after this initialization.
      }
   }
}
```

In this class I tried both approaches, but none work. Thank you for answers or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I really want to thank for all answers and suggestions I tried to implement both answers on my solution, but unfortunately unsuccessfully. Main reason that I wasn't focusing on class where I am implemented whole iOS toolbar and it was on my iOS project.

On iOS toolbar I just wrote simple if statement:

```
var currentPage = ((NavigationPage)Element).CurrentPage;
if (currentPage != null && currentPage is ContentPage)
{
    TopViewController.NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = new UIBarButtonItem[0];
                return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `PPoPage` is a different page instance to `MainPage`, and thus contains its' own ToolbarItems collection.

Try `main.ToolbarItems.Clear()` in place of `this.ToolbarItems.Clear()`, assuming the `main` property has been initialised, or you can access the top-level current page with `Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.CurrentPage`.

Comment: Well, when I do like this main.ToolbarItems.Clear();  I am getting on Main.cs error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1):

I had task to change visibility of toolbar item and I created base content page with wrapper around `ToolbarItems` collection. My sample could help you:

[sample on git](https://github.com/gromadskyi/SuperForms/blob/master/SuperForms/Samples/SuperForms.Samples/SuperForms.Samples/CustomToolbarPage.xaml)

[some "tutorial" that I've posted on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135481/changing-visibility-of-toolbaritem-xamarin-forms)

[image]